# Input fields do not respond to changing state to empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

How come after I post something, the input fields' values remain the same, even after I change the state of data to null? 
I console.logged the state and after a post the data state variable is correctly set to an empty object, but the state of the inputs don't change. 
Please advise.

```
var AccountView = React.createClass({

getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
        data: {},
        users: [],
    };
},

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        data: {},
        users: {},
    };
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/react-webpack/js/source/controllers/get_accounts.php",
        async: "false",
        dataType: "json",
        sucess: function(json) {
            console.log("success!");
            console.log(json);      

        },
        error:function(x, e) {
            alert(e);
        },
        complete: function(a, data) {
            var users = JSON.parse(a.responseText);
            this.setState({
                users: users,
            });
        }.bind(this)
    });
},

handleChange: function(e) {
    var data = this.state.data;
    data[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
        data: data,
    });
},

handleSave: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var users = this.state.users;
    users.push(this.state.data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/react-webpack/js/source/controllers/post_accounts.php",
        type: "post",
        data: this.state.data,
        success: function(data, a) {
            this.setState({
                data: {},
            });
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(e) {

        },
        complete: function(a, data) {
            this.setState({
                data: {},
                users: users,
            });
        }.bind(this)
    });
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <form method="post">    
                <dl id="form" className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <dt>Firstname</dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input name="firstname" type="text" value={this.state.data.firstname} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </dd>
                        <dt>Lastname</dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input name="lastname" type="text" value={this.state.data.lastname} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </dd>
                        <dt>Password</dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input name="password" type="text" value={this.state.data.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </dd>
                        <dt>Email Address</dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input name="emailaddress" type="text" value={this.state.data.emailaddress} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </dd>
                        <dt>Submit</dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSave} />
                        </dd>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Firstname</th>
                                    <th>Lastname</th>
                                    <th>Password</th>
                                    <th>Email address</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {_.map(this.state.users, function(user) {
                            return (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{user.firstname}</td>
                                        <td>{user.lastname}</td>
                                        <td>{user.password}</td>
                                        <td>{user.emailaddress}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    );  
                            })}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </dl>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

});

module.exports = AccountView;
```

Comment: I am curious to what happens `component.forceUpdate(callback)`. The `callback` being a function executing your setState code.

Comment: @MichaelBruce I'm not sure if i'm doing it right, but in the complete section of the post ajax call, I used this.forceUpate(callback), where callback is the setState code, and the code behaves the same

Comment: send me your git link?

Comment: https://github.com/DannyGarciaMartin/react-webpack/tree/master/js/source

Comment: I have not taken a webpack course yet, but most of the time I start up with npm run start. If not that, at least a basic js file with node. How can I start your app?

Comment: @MichaelBruce try webpack in the main directory (inside react-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found to work based off of James Ganong's work, although note in my work environment setting the state to clear isn't necessary where the problem: null object not clearing the inputs doesn't exist.

```
handleSave: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var users = this.state.users;
    users.push(this.state.data);
    $.ajax({
    url: "/react-webpack/js/source/controllers/post_accounts.php",
    type: "post",
    data: this.state.data,
    success: function(data, a) {
        this.setState({
            data: {},
        });
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(e) {

    },
    complete: function(a, data) {
       var clear = {
            firstname: '',
            lastname: '',
            password: '',
            emailaddress: '',
       };
       this.setState({
            data: clear,
            users: users,
        });
    }.bind(this)
});
},
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `value={this.state.data.firstname}`on an input, if `this.state.data.firstname` is null or undefined and there is already a value set on the input, it keeps it. So when you set `data` to an empty object, everything is passing null/undefined to the inputs.

So, when you update your state, instead of setting `data` to an empty object, reset all the values to an empty string. A good way to do this is to first create a new initialState var outside of your class with the full shape of the state and then use it in your `getInitialState` method:

```
var initialState = {
    data: {
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      password: '',
      emailaddress: ''
    },
    users: [] // also not this should be an array instead of an object
};
```

Inside your class:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  // we're cloning initialState so it doesn't get modified directly
  // as we want to use it later to reset the state
  return Object.assign({}, initialState); 
},
```

Next, instead of doing `this.setState({ data: {} })` do this:

```
this.setState({
  data: Object.assign({}, initialState.data)
});
```

---

On a side note, you also have two places where you're mutating the state directly - `handleChange` and `handleSave`:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
    var data = this.state.data;
    data[e.target.name] = e.target.value; // this is directly mutating the state
    this.setState({
        data: data,
    });
},

// ...

handleSave: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var users = this.state.users;
  users.push(this.state.data); // this is directly mutating the state
  // ...
```

Mutating the state outside of `setState()` can cause some weird unintended side effects and generally is a cause of poor performance.

To fix it, you first copy the state data, add to it, then set it (only requires simple changes):

```
handleChange: function(e) {
    var data = Object.assign({}, this.state.data);
    data[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
        data: data,
    });
},

// ...

handleSave: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var users = this.state.users.slice();
  users.push(this.state.data);
  // ...
```

Comment: Interesting take on this problem, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. Thanks for your input anyways. I'm still not sure what my problem in my code is. I think the handleChange is fine. Even this.forceUpdate() doesn't work, so it's almost as if the state isn't registered as changing.

Comment: Yes, as you've found, my answer didn't answer your direct question, but it is a separate issue that can have other side effects. You never want to mutate state outside of `setState()`. You've got another location where you're doing this as well in `handleSave()` where you have `users.push(this.state.data);` which is mutating users directly on the state. I'm still looking into it, and hopefully will be able to update this answer!

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work. In the initialstate variable, I think this could be problematic because I want to set the users as the users that have already been entered. If it helps, in my work environment we have something exactly like this in setting the state variables, and it works in clearing the inputs. Not sure why it doesn't in my example...

Comment: I did find a temporary solution involving what you were mentioning in setting cleared values. I'll post the solution.

Comment: I don't see how the initialState variable would cause an issue with initializing the users to a different value. Here's my solution in its entirety working: https://gitlab.com/ganong/stack-overflow-42730616   git clone it, then run `npm install` then `npm run serve` to see it in action.